# Rails 3.1 Rendering view to string so that all assets in the html have absolute paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets, absolute-path, render-to-string

I need the HTML generated with absolute asset paths so that I can then feed the HTML to a PDF generation engine. So the route would be something like

```
/report.pdf
```

which would generate the view for

```
/report.html
```

and then post process that with the PDF generation engine.

```
http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string
```

will get me half way there but will leave the assets with their relative paths.

Comment: Can't you just add the paths whenever its processed by the engine?

Comment: The top level is easy as I can just inline the CSS and JS with a custom tag. However deep in the templates there will be references to images that I need absolute paths for. I guess I could monkey match the image_tag helper. That might work.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue while generating pdf.
I have set asset_host in environments

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

Or before render_to_string Add this line

```
host = ActionController::Base.asset_host
ActionController::Base.asset_host = request.protocol + request.host_with_port if host.blank?
```

I am using in my gem [acts_as_flying_saucer](https://github.com/amardaxini/acts_as_flying_saucer/)

I hope this is helpful
But i have tested on 2.x and rails 3.0.x.
I haven't tested with rails 3.1 i will test and let you know as early as possible